# Unable to send or receive email in Roundcube webmail vesta

Tags: oracle, email, centos, roundcube, vesta

My machine is centOS 7 and the instance is running on oracle cloud. I have installed Vesta on it and also installed the SSL.

I am trying to send emails. When I try to send it, it shows that It is sent but not actually sending it. Also, I am not receiving any email.

I am very new to this. Can you please help?

Thank you in advance.

I want to send and receive emails in Roundcube.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe port 25 being blocked by default is preventing you from sending e-mails.

https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/releasenotes/changes/f7e95770-9844-43db-916c-6ccbaf2cfe24/